# how to make a connection via bluetooth with phonegap 3.5.0 to an Arduino?

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth, arduino

Someone has an example or something? I've been proving this plugin https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial but i cant make it work.
how i call those function in the .js the plugin has?
I just want to send to my arduino some characters and receive data from the arduino to my android phone too.